# NServicebus DNS Entry for Machine location

Tags: msmq, message, nservicebus, queuing

I am trying to use a DNS entry for my NServicebus queue endpoint but no messages are being sent. It works fine when I enter the computer name or an IPAddress. I can ping the record and it resolves correctly so i'm wondering if it is possible to use a DNS record? Here is my config:

```
<MessageEndpointMappings>
  <!--These are the messages which need to be sent to the BusService  -->
  <add Messages="BusCommon.BusHeartBeatMessage, BusCommon" Endpoint="BusService@broker.mydomain.com" />
</MessageEndpointMappings>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Msmq and DNS is a bit tricky.

http://blogs.msdn.com/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/02/11/how-to-deliver-msmq-messages-to-a-new-machine.aspx

http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/nservicebus/message/6986

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;142309

Hope this helps!